# Java/Selenium/Appium Android APK Device Chromedriver Issue

Tags: java, android, cordova, selenium, appium

This is a Sencha Touch 2 application, Cordova wrapped, and built as an APK, that I am testing on a physical device.
The second screen in the application after log in is entirely wrapped in an android.webkit.WebView, and I am unable to interact with any of the elements that I can find (typically in the wrong spot or completely off the screen) using UIAutomatorviewer.
My last ditch attempt at getting this to work was to switch to the WEBVIEW_com.tgs.senchabuild context on that page (and in future pages) in able to interact with aforementioned UI elements.
Now that I have had webcontent debugging enabled on the APK, I am now getting this error that my chrome version does not meeting the requirement of being >= 33.0.1750.0, which it clearly does.

I'm testing a hybrid Cordova application and finally was able to switch to WebView, however when it does, Chromedriver fails launch:

My capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.tgs.senchabuild");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("udid", n10Udid);
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 10");
```

Appium output (at least the piece that gives me an error):

> ERROR: error: Chromedriver create session did not work. Status was 200 and body was {"sessionId":"fde047ed1f488a11366a6f3a10c25458","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: **Chrome version must be >= 33.0.1750.0\n**  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)"}}

I am so close to getting this darn automation to work...please HELP!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using it on a 4.4 i suggest you go for 4.2. There is a problem with chromedriver and 4.4 devices

Answer (score 0):

This is same issue reported: [Appium throws "chrome not reachable" sporadically when switch a context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376582/appium-throws-chrome-not-reachable-sporadically-when-switch-a-context/34715600#34715600)

I am reply here again:
I could get a fix by monitoring chromedriver all the time during test execution, chromedriver becomes unresponsive while switching back to webview from natiove_app. I developed a small piece of code available at https://github.com/mi2pankaj/chromeDriverHandler, it has solved my all problems, just add this jar chromedriverHandler.jar to your project and use ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().start(); in your @beforeclass / @beforetest and ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().stop(); in your @afterclass / @aftertest.